# Visual/partially-visual HTML editor which won't "do stuff behind your back"

Tags: html, html-editor, wysiwyg

I need an HTML editor with the following features:

Required features:

- Gratis
- Runs on GNU/Linux, preferably tolerant to any desktop environment
- Runs on x86_64 machines
- Actively maintained or developed
- Not very heavy (yes, I realize this is subjective; exercise judgement)
- Some kind of visuality - either you edit the page the way it'll look when rendered; or there's a preview; or the HTML is visualized to make all of its structure accessible etc.
- Never inserts any HTML which you did not clearly indicate you want in the document: extra wrapping spans, extra attributes of its own, all sorts of boilerplate etc.

Desired features:

- Ability to see the page in its final, styled form
- Inteface allows you to add any structurally-valid HTML, even if the editor/renderer doesn't know what it does/what it means (e.g. you can make `<a id="some_id">blah</a>` into `<a id="some_id" foo="bar">blah</a>`)
- Rich text-editor-like functionality, the more the merrier
- Runs on Windows too
- Ability to edit the plain HTML source of segments of the document

Features which don't matter at all:

- Support for dynamic content, e.g. Javascript, and its preview
- Support for non-HTML markup languages

In a nutshell, you could say I'd like something like LyX but for HTML rather than LaTeX.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? [BlueGriffon](http://bluegriffon.org/)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos: I don't know, is it? ... anyway, I'll try it.